# How do I solve this: `Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x0`

Tags: anchor, rent, typescript, client, tests

I have this in my lib.rs file:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
#[account(
    init,
    payer = authority,
    space = 8 + Config::SIZE,
    seeds = ["config".as_bytes().as_ref()],
    bump 
)]
config: Box<Account<'info, Config>>,

#[account(mut)]
authority: Signer<'info>,
native_token_mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
system_program: Program<'info, System>,
rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>
```

}

and in my test.ts file:

```
await program.methods
.initialize()
.accounts({
  config: configAddress,
  authority: admin.publicKey,
  nativeTokenMint: nativeMintAddress,
  //systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
  //rent: anchor.web3.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY
})
.signers([admin])
.rpc();
```

Running the test passes on the first try each time I rebuild and redeploy the program but fails everytime after that with the error above. I've checked and now I know that 0x0 means "Lamport balance below rent-exempt threshold" but I have no idea what that means and even if I did, how to solve this error.

Comment: instruction 0 is `SystemInstruction::CreateAccount` the system program's error 0 is [`AccountInUse`](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/a94920a4eadf1008fc292e47e041c1b3b0d949df/sdk/program/src/system_instruction.rs#L21-L22), not sub-rent-exempt lamports balance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the first call your accounts will be initialized. On subsequent calls, the initialization will naturally fail because the account is already initialized... :-) Did you expect a different behavior?

Also, better remove the comment marks for `systemProgram` and `rent` in the JS code, your instruction expects these.

Comment: Thanks. It had me stuck for a few days. What happened was I was creating a PDA account with only a constant seed. So I wasn't getting varying addresses on each test like I would if there was a different `anchor.web3.Keypair.generate()` account each time

Comment: Ah got it. That I couldn't see from your question. Glad you solved it now.

Answer (score 1):

To understand the errors you have to check the error.rs in solana library, this is the file: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/ea354ab358021aa08f774e2d4028b33ec56d4180/token/program/src/error.rs

Looks like you have "Lamport balance below rent-exempt threshold", I think you have to fund your account.

I hope this helps.

**Errata:**

By mistake I pointed out to an incorrect file thinking this was related to token program, the correct file is the one already pointed in the first comment by trent.sol:

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/a94920a4eadf1008fc292e47e041c1b3b0d949df/sdk/program/src/system_instruction.rs#L21-L22

Comment: the cited error references instruction index 0, which is a system program instruction, not an SPL Token program instruction.  `InstructionError:Custom(u32)`'s value is defined by the program that declared the instruction which raised the error

Comment: Added an errata to explain the error